# Find String in a String latin letters

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$var = "User_èéàùìò";
if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map("strtolower", str_split($var)), array("ì", "è", "é", "ò", "à"))))
```

echo "true";
else
  echo "false";

This returns "false". What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression (i.e. `preg_match()`) or `strpbrk()` which may actually be more appropriate here?

Comment: Because `array_insersect()` returns an empty array.

Comment: At first I should say, use function latin9_to_utf8($latin9str) as $var=latin9_to_utf8($var); also see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: @ShivanshuSrivastava latin9_to_utf8??? This is not a function

Comment: its an user defined function at php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php , user-comments., you can search by F3.

Answer (score 1):

You know that php string function actually work with binary data but not with text. Encoding of your text is UTF8. So you cannot use `str_split` on it.

```
$var = "User_èéàùìò"; // has 11 characters
str_split($var); // has 17 items
```

Better to use regular expressions which support multibyte characters.

```
$var = "User_èéàùìò";
var_dump(preg_match('/[ìèéòà]/iu', $var)); // i - case insensitive, u - utf character
```